# Why does clojure give this arity error

Tags: clojure

I have the function definition below for map-edit

```
(def map-edit
  (fn [m lst k f]
    (if (car lst)
      (assoc m
             (car lst)
             (map-edit (get m (car lst) {}) k f))
      (assoc m k (f (get m k))))))
```

When I try to call this function in my repl

```
(map-edit {} (list "oeu") "oeuoeu" (fn [q] "oeu"))
```

I get an error for Arity

```
ArityException Wrong number of args (3) passed to: core/map-edit  clojure.lang.AFn.throwArity (AFn.java:429)
```

Why does it think I am only passing 3 arguments?

```
; CIDER 0.8.2 (Java 1.8.0_121, Clojure 1.8.0, nREPL 0.2.12)
```

Comment: Just as a side note - it looks like you are trying to re-implement the `clojure.core`'s function `update-in` - it might be helpful for you to look [at its source code](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.9.0-alpha14/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L6054) as an example of how this kind of recursion is usually done in Clojure.

Comment: @AlephAleph You are totally right. Thanks for the link and the comment (using update-in should be the accepted answer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that you have these definitions

```
(def car first)
(def cdr rest)
```

The recursive call to map-edit only uses 3 arguments

The line probably should be

```
(map-edit (get m (car lst) {}) (cdr lst) k f))
```

Comment: @amalloy I used triple backtick (```) to denote the code before. What is the best way to do that?

Comment: You can look at the edit I made: full-line code snippets should be indented by four spaces. Stack Overflow's editor has a button that will do that for you, as well.

Answer (score 0):

**Note**

Assuming that [@SultanLegend's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44340206/1562315) is correct (not accepted as I write), the core [`update-in`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/update-in) does what you require. You could define ...

```
(defn map-edit [m lst k f]
  (update-in m (conj (vec lst) k) f))

(map-edit {} (list "oeu") "oeuoeu" (fn [q] "oeu"))
=> {"oeu" {"oeuoeu" "oeu"}}
```